# Running Jekyll Serve on Debian Chromebook

Tags: ruby, debian, jekyll

I am working on a Chromebook, where I have setup a debian chroot.

I ran the following commands with no problems:

```
$ gem install jekyll
$ jekyll new myblog
$ cd myblog
```

When running:

```
~/myblog $ jekyll serve
```

I receive the following error:

```
/home/damon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.1/lib/liquid/htmltags.rb:43: warning:  
     duplicated key at line 46 ignored: "index0"

Configuration file: /home/damon/myblog/_config.yml
        Source: /home/damon/myblog
        Destination: /home/damon/myblog/_site
     Generating... 
Liquid Exception: Failed to get header. in _posts/2014-12-28-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  Failed to get header.
```

I have tried changing Ruby versions from 2.2 and 1.9.

Does anyone have an idea one how to resolve this issue?

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Most likely you haven't installed Python 2.7.3 - Do not install Python 3 since Pygments (the highlighter) doesn't support Python 3. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1181. A re-install of python can also fix it.

Comment: a `jekyll serve --trace` can be useful

Comment: @limelights why don't your put your comment as an answer ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel It's not worthy, IMO. I just did a quick google of the error

Comment: @limelights but you're right, it's clearly `pygments:popen:get_header` that doesn't receive headers from pygments/mentos.py. And even if you answer come from a google search, it certainly does the job.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Posted as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you haven't installed Python 2.7.3 - **Do not** install Python 3 since Pygments (the highlighter) doesn't support Python 3. [See related Github Issue here](http://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1181).

A re-install of Python can also fix it.

Comment: Prior to asking this question on StackOverflow, I did see this while searching google.

Comment: So I ran sudo apt-get install python2.7 and it seems to installed successfully. However when I type python -v it states that the command was not found. I could be missing something simple here, thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: If I type python2.7 it will open up a python interpreter